# Adding a TastyPie ModelResource to another ModelResource connected by a Django OneToOne Relationship

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two django models that are connected by a OneToOne relationship and I am having trouble seeing how to connect them in a Tastypie ModelResource.

Instead of posting some new models I will borrow the models defined in [Including child resources in a Django Tastypie API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815756/including-child-resources-in-a-django-tastypie-api) to show where I am not getting how to do this. Using the `Ticket` and `TicketComment` models, imagine that the `TicketComment` was like this:

```
class TicketComment(models.Model):
    ticket = models.OneToOneField('Ticket')
```

instead of using the ForeignKey field. I have seen the docs as well as posts like the above which are using the `ToManyField` and `ToOneField`. But that doesn't appear to work in my situation since the `Ticket` does not reference the `TicketComment`. What I want to do is be able to create an API that lists the `TicketComment` in the `Ticket`. Tastypie rightly throws an exception saying that `TicketComment` fields don't exist in the `Ticket` model. Is there a way to get the nice serialized `TicketComment` into the `Ticket` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [attribute](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#attribute) arg that tells tastypie what field it should use. Ticket is referenced TicketComment by reverse relation. By default it will be a lowercased model name so in your example it will be ticketcomment. But i recommend you to set a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute in your model explicitly so you will know how it will be connected.

So in your tastypie you should do this :

```
class TicketResource(ModelResource):
   comment = fields.OneToOneField('TicketCommentResource', 'ticketcomment')
```

And it will work fine. The second arg in OneToOneField is a attribute.

Comment: this works for me: comment = fields.OneToOneField('TicketCommentResource', 'ticketcomment')

Is that what you meant?

Comment: and to serialize the `TicketComment` inside the `Ticket` use `OneToOneField('TicketCommentResource', 'ticketcomment', full=True)`

Comment: It fails for me on POST with following error -  in hydrate\n    value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 154, in hydrate\n    elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute, None):\n\n  File \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 343, in __get__\n    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n"}" Were you trying to do POSTor GET?