# Django-Tastypie self children

Tags: django, tastypie

Trying to make api for multiple subtasks.
I have the task model, that can have another task as a parent:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    parent_task = models.ForeignKey("Task", null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Now I'm trying to make tastypie resource:

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    parent_task = fields.ForeignKey(TaskResource, 'parent_task', full=False) <-- ERROR HERE

    class Meta:
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'task'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']
        include_resource_uri = False

    def dehydrate(self, bundle, for_list=False):
        bundle.data["subtasks"] = "how?" <-- HOW??
        return bundle
```

Thanks for your time.

P.S. I need something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Task 1",
        "subtasks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Task 1",
                "subtasks": [...]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Task 2",
        "subtasks": "how?"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a copy of [Including child resources in a Django Tastypie API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815756/including-child-resources-in-a-django-tastypie-api) but not exactly.

1. So your first problem is that you specify relation to self wrong. It should be just `self`:

   ```
   parent_task = fields.ForeignKey('self', 'parent_task', null=True, full=False)
   ```
2. Secondly, notice `null=True` - parent could be `null`.
3. Lastly, you just need to add another relation field and ask for the full details

   ```
   subtasks = fields.ToManyField('self', 'task_set', full=True)
   ```

   `task_set` is a `related_name` for the `Task.parent_task` field.

The resulting code is:

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    parent_task = fields.ForeignKey('self', 'parent_task', null=True, full=False)
    subtasks = fields.ToManyField('self', 'subtasks', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'task'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']
        include_resource_uri = False
```

And the result:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "previous": null, 
        "total_count": 3,  
        "offset": 0,  
        "limit": 20, 
        "next": null
    },  
    "objects": [
        {
            "parent_task": null, 
            "subtasks": [
                {
                    "parent_task": "/api/v1/task/1/", 
                    "subtasks": [], 
                    "id": 2,  
                    "name": "Root's Child 1"
                },
                {
                    "parent_task": "/api/v1/task/1/", 
                    "subtasks": [], 
                    "id": 3,  
                    "name": "Root's Child 2"
                }
            ],
            "id": 1,  
            "name": "Root Task"
        },
        {
            "parent_task": "/api/v1/task/1/", 
            "subtasks": [], 
            "id": 2,  
            "name": "Root's Child 1"
        },
        {
            "parent_task": "/api/v1/task/1/", 
            "subtasks": [], 
            "id": 3,  
            "name": "Root's Child 2"
        }
    ]   
}
```